# Dead code warning in try-with-resources, but not in translated try-catch-finally

Tags: java, eclipse, try-with-resources

The following code uses the [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) construction introduced in Java 8.  The **occasionallyThrow()** method is declared to throw an **OccasionalException**, the **Resource**'s **close()** method to throw a **CloseException**.  Eclipse (Version: Neon Release (4.6.0), Build id: 20160613-1800) adds a warning on the line marked with **// dead code** that the branch is dead code.  Implicitly, Eclipse affirms that the line marked with **// alive code** is *not* dead code.

```
Object tryWithResources() throws OccasionalException {
    Object value = null;
    try (Resource resource = new Resource()) {
        occasionallyThrow();
        value = new Object();
    }
    catch (CloseException e) {
        if (value == null) {
            // alive code
        }
        else {
            // dead code
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

I'm confused by this.  If **occasionallyThrow()** throws its **OccasionalException**, then the `try`-with-resources should catch that as the primary exception and then attempt to close the resource.  If closing the resource throws a **CloseException**, then it will be suppressed under the **OccasionalException**, so there won't be the **CloseException** to catch.  So, the only time there should be **CloseException** to catch is when the block within the **try** completed successfully which means that **value** is non-null.  So it seems like the "dead code" is actually alive, and the "alive code" is actually dead.  I'm not sure what a compiler is actually expected to recognize here, but at the very least, it seems like the "dead code" here should *not* be called dead.

What makes this more complicated is that the translated form without using the try-with-resources form doesn't get marked with any dead code warnings at all.  (I'm fairly confident that I got this translation right, based on [14.20.3.2. Extended try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2), but I wouldn't be completely surprised if there's bug here…)

```
Object expandedTry() throws OccasionalException {
    Object value = null;
    try {
        Resource resource = new Resource();
        Throwable $primary = null;
        try {
            occasionallyThrow();
            value = new Object();
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            $primary = t;
            throw t;
        }
        finally {
            if (resource != null) {
                if ($primary != null) {
                    try {
                        resource.close();
                    }
                    catch (Throwable $suppressed) {
                        $primary.addSuppressed($suppressed);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    resource.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (CloseException e) {
        if (value == null) {
            // alive (not dead!)
        }
        else {
            // alive
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Am I missing something that would make either branch in the if-else dead in one of these, but not in the other?

### Full Code

Here's the full code with definitions of the auxiliary exception types, the **Resource** class, and the top-level class.

```
public class TestTryWithResources {

    /** Exception thrown by Resource's close() method */
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    static class CloseException extends Exception {}

    /** AutoCloseable declared to throw a CloseException */ 
    static class Resource implements AutoCloseable {
        @Override
        public void close() throws CloseException {}
    }

    /** An occasionally thrown exception */
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    static class OccasionalException extends Exception {}

    /** Method declared to throw an occasional exception */
    void occasionallyThrow() throws OccasionalException {}

    /*
     * Method using try-with-resources.  Eclipse warns that the 
     * portion marked with "// dead code" is Dead code.
     */
    Object tryWithResources() throws OccasionalException {
        Object value = null;
        try (Resource resource = new Resource()) {
            occasionallyThrow();
            value = new Object();
        }
        catch (CloseException e) {
            if (value == null) {
                // alive code
            }
            else {
                // dead code
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    /*
     * Method not using try-with-resources.  This is the translation
     * of the try-with-resources in tryWithResources, according to 
     * [14.20.3 try-with-resources][1].  Eclipse does not warn about 
     * any of the code being Dead code.
     * 
     * [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3 
     */
    Object expandedTry() throws OccasionalException {
        Object value = null;
        try {
            Resource resource = new Resource();
            Throwable $primary = null;
            try {
                occasionallyThrow();
                value = new Object();
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                $primary = t;
                throw t;
            }
            finally {
                if (resource != null) {
                    if ($primary != null) {
                        try {
                            resource.close();
                        }
                        catch (Throwable $suppressed) {
                            $primary.addSuppressed($suppressed);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        resource.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (CloseException e) {
            if (value == null) {
                // alive
            }
            else {
                // alive
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

### Responses to Comments

[Amin J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39599357/1281433) suggested a workaround of using the resource after setting *value* to change Eclipse's code analysis.  This doesn't work though.  After using the resource, e.g., by printing it, the dead code warning is still present in both Luna and Neon:

[image: Luna dead code warning, in spite of using resource after assigning to value]

[image: Neon dead code warning, in spite of using resource after assigning to value]

Comment: Perhaps this [Bug 366277 - \[1.7\] Incorrect dead code/null value analysis in try-with-resources](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366277), although that's 5 years old now...

Comment: I am not sure if you can catch an exception that is thrown during closing that is done by try-with-resources in a catch-block that belongs to the try-block. What happens if you change CloseException to be a checked exception? And what happens if you additionally move the catch to a surrounding try?

Comment: @mm759 Responding to middle question first: CloseException *is* a checked exception.  I ensured that by defining it here as a subclass of Exception (not as a subclass of RuntimeException).

Comment: @mm759 For the first question, the behavior of try-with-resources with a catch is described by [14.20.3.2. Extended try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2). `try ResourceSpecification Block Catches Finally` (which is what I'm using (without the optional Finally), is translated as `try { try ResourceSpecification Block } Catches Finally`. So you *can* catch the exception thrown by the implicit close when the body didn't throw an exception, so (second question) the translation already "move[s] the catch to a surrounding try [.]"

Comment: On a lunch break and can't test. Does occasionallyThrow() contrary to the name, always throw an OccasionalException? If so wouldn't the line after it be inaccessible because tryWithResources() handles OccasionalException via throwing it? That would mean value would never change from null and would make the else block inaccessible.

Comment: @Zachary Actually, in the provided implementation, it *never* throws, but is *declared* with `throws OccasionalException`.  But I've tried both ways (with it always throwing and with it never throwing), with the same results.

Comment: javac does not generate a warning so this seems related to Eclipse. The bug mentioned by @JoshuaTaylor has status "new" so that would imply it isn't fixed?

Comment: @Rodney That's *if* it's the same bug (which it's looking like), but there might be some difference that I haven't noticed.  And, as you mention, that's marked "NEW", not even "CONFIRMED", so there may be some difference.

Comment: It might not be "CONFIRMED" but I can personally confirm that it still happens on Eclipse 4.5.2. Specifically, code marked as "dead code" clearly generates output when the test case is run. And again, only Eclipse generates the warning - not javac

Comment: @Rodney Yes, and 4.5.2 is still behind the version that I've been using (Neon Release (4.6.0), as mentioned in the question).  It seems like this have been around for a while.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the static code analyzer thinks that that the resource is going to be closed right after the try declaration while according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) tutorial the resource is closed after the statement.

*The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.*

So for instance if you change your code to use the resource after value is is (code below) it won't warn you about the dead code (tested on Eclipse Luna however).

```
Object tryWithResources() throws OccasionalException {
    Object value = null;
    try (Resource resource = new Resource()) {
        occasionallyThrow();
        value = new Object();
        resource.someMethod(); // using the resource, so eclipse thinks it's not closed yet (correctly)
    }
    catch (CloseException e) {
        if (value == null) {
            // alive code
        }
        else {
            // dead code
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the actual code I tested with usage of resource (in this case reader) after setting the value.

```
        Object val = null;

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\file.txt"))) {
            val = new Object();
            System.out.println("got here");
            reader.readLine();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("io ex");
            if ( val == null){

            }
            else{

            }
        }
```

Comment: Using the resource after setting *value* does not eliminate the dead code warning in Eclipse.  I've updated the question to show that the warning is still present.

Comment: Then it may be specific to Eclipse Neon. I tried it in Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Nope, I tried in both Luna and Eclipse.  The warning is present in both of them. I updated my question again to show both.

Comment: Interesting. I also tried in Neon. It goes away in Neon as well. I updated the answer to include the actual code ( I'm trying with a BufferedReader since I don't have your code)

Comment: Ok I think I know what that is. the readLine() method also throws IOException that's probably why eclipse now is convinced that the exception can be thrown after value is set.

Comment: Yes, that sort of usage might get rid of the warning, but in my example, I'm specifically trying to ensure that the close() method and the methods in the block() *don't* throw the same exception type.  That why I'm using a resource whose close() throws CloseException, and a method that throws OccasionalException, so that we can be sure that if we're seeing a CloseException, it *must* have occurred during the automatic-closing, and that it must be in a case where the body completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question of *why* Eclipse is generating the warning that it is, or whether it should be or not, but this is a workaround that at least eliminates the warning for the time being.  Rather than putting the conditional in the **catch** block, you can call another method with the value being tested as well as a the exception, and from that method test whether the object is null and then do whatever needs to be done:

```
Object tryWithResources() throws OccasionalException {
    Object value = null;
    try (Resource resource = new Resource()) {
        occasionallyThrow();
        value = new Object();
        System.out.println(resource.toString());
    }
    catch (CloseException e) {
        catchBlock(value, e);  // call auxiliary method
    }
    return value;
}

void catchBlock(Object value, CloseException e) {
    if (value == null) {
        // then
    }
    else {
        // else
    }
}
```