# Eclipse gives dead code warning for reachable code (variant)

Tags: java, eclipse, dead-code

I have following code:

```
public String myMethod(String keyValue) {
    Map<String, Integer> keyValueToRowIndex = ...
    Integer rowIndex = (keyValue == null) ? 0 : keyValueToRowIndex.get(keyValue);
    if (rowIndex == null)
      return null;
    ...
}
```

Eclipse gives a "dead code" warning on the `return null;`. Removing the test for `keyValue == null` also removes the warning but I don't see how that extra test makes the return statement dead code. Clearly if the map contains no entry for some non-null `keyValue`, then `rowIndex` can still be null. Or am I missing something here?

I've seen similar Eclipse issues ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351907/eclipse-gives-dead-code-warning-for-reachable-code) for instance), but this one seems a different and more trivial one.

Comment: What is your Java version? there is a difference between Java 7 and 8. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25417505/5168011

Comment: I had it on Java8, but the warning is there both with 7 and 8.

Comment: Also it throws NPE in both cases (see comment on accepted answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that line 3 is interpreted as

```
Integer rowIndex = Integer.valueOf((keyValue == null) ? 0 : keyValueToRowIndex.get(keyValue).intValue());
```

(so both arguments to ?: are unified as `int`) - oddly enogh, Eclipse now shows no warning, even if it is now obvious that rowIndex is never null...

You might also replace the `0` with `Integer.valueOf(0)` to make the warning disappear.

Comment: You're right, the issue is not in Eclipse but in my code. The ternary expression provokes an autobox to `int`, so if `keyValueToRowIndex.get(keyValue)` returns null, a NullPointerException is thrown on line 3. Thanks for pointing this out. Replacing the `0` with `Integer.valueOf(0)` solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The (surprising) short answer: *Eclipse is right! This is dead code!*

**Reason**

The important part is the ternary expression in the following line of code:

```
    Integer rowIndex = (keyValue == null) ? 0 : keyValueToRowIndex.get(keyValue);
```

The [Java language specification (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/) says about the ["Conditional Operator ?"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/), that, if the first expression is of type `int`, and the second expression is of type `Integer`, the type of the entire expression will be `int`.

In your case, the first expression is the constant literal value `0`, which is an `int`. The second expression is the result of the `get` method, which returns an object of type `Integer`. So according to the JLS, the entire expression has primitive type `int`!

This means, if the second expression (the `get`-call) will be evaluated, the result will be unboxed from `Integer` to `int`. This `int` value will then be auto-boxed again into an `Integer` to be able to assign it to the left operand, `rowIndex`.

But what happens, if the map returns a `null` value? In this case, unboxing from `Integer` to `int` is not possible, and a `NullPointerExpression` will be thrown!

So eclipse is right, as your expression can never return `null`, `rowIndex` will never be `null` either and the then-block of your if-statement will never be executed and hence is dead code!

**Solution**

The solution is simple: Use an `Integer` object instead of an primitive `int` value for your first expression:

```
Integer rowIndex = (keyValue == null) ? Integer.valueOf(0) : keyValueToRowIndex.get(keyValue);
```

Comment: thanks, yes this is the full answer. I had already deduced that from @Gyro Gearless' answer, and accepted that. +1 for the references.